# How to find {CFIDE-HOME} in Coldfusion

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-8

any one has idea, how can I find `{CFIDE-HOME}` path in my server? this is for coldfusion 8.0.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you need to get this path from your application, or do you need it because it's not set up on your site and you need to find it to get your app working correctly?

If you need this from your app, you should use `#ExpandPath("/CFIDE")#`.

If you need this because it's not set up correctly and you just need to find the directory on disk, then your best bet is to simply search your hard drive for the CFIDE directory. If you installed CF under JRUN, then the CFIDE directory will be under each server instance's directory. If you install CF as a standalone app then it's most likely under `/ColdFusion8/wwwroot/CFIDE`.

Dan

Answer (score 1):

Check neo-runtime.xml. Based upon your installation path of that file will be ColdFusion8/lib/neo-runtime.xml or WEB-INF\cfusion\lib\neo-runtime.xml

Answer (score 0):

you could just do a search for CFIDE/ on your platform if you don't where ColdFusion is installed.